# Testing in jupyter with pandas and run it into production python code and give a diffrent results/error

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I have a very wirdt issue, i'm working on a issue where i'm in jumpty have this code.

```
df_mpg = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mongo_conn['prices'].aggregate([{
    '$match': {
       'group-key': name,
        'method': 'business'
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        'uuid': 1,
        'price': 1,
        'unlock': '$properties.unlock.value'
    }
}]))

df_mpg.set_index('uuid', inplace=True)
df_mpg.index = df_mpg.index.str.encode('utf-8')
```

The problem is, when i move my code to the part of my normal python application, it get a error, and i really not understand it.

its say the uuid is a key-error, and its not make eny sens at all

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/parisnakitakejser/Desktop/pandas/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'uuid'
```

its there somthing in jupyter there work with pandas in a diffrend way as normal application in python or what can the error be?

Comment: If test `print (df_mpg.columns.tolist())` what is returned? There is `uuid` ?

Comment: i have trying both head, iloc and so, in jupyter its showing the right data, live its do not, its showing a empty dataframe, its very wirdt thing.

Comment: Doooh, what i reilay, 1,5day hard fighting is.... my prod code connect to wrong database.....

thanks for you feedback, my bug are now magic gone!